# Array not being written to - Async NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

```
var songs = [];

request.get(getSongs, function(error, response, body){
  append(songs,body);
});

function append(arr, data){
  for (let j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
    console.log(data.items[j].track.name);
    arr.push(songs,data.items[j].track.name);
  }
}



console.log(songs); //outputs '[]'
```

I've google a lot and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

For some context, request.get() returns between 1 and 20 objects, and I'd like to add an attribute (or more) of all of them to the array 'songs'. They console.log() correctly and their positions are correct, but when I log the array, it appears to be empty.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What is request? Is that a library? or nodes http class

Comment: A request calls spotify's API and passes in this case a certain number and order of songs that have already been specified. The data returns properly, and I have no problem console.logging it, I just can't figure out how to store it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that you're logging the array synchronously. Currently, your program currently runs as follows:

1. Defines an empty array
2. Kicks off a request to get songs
3. Defines your append function
4. logs the empty array
5. Gets back the songs
6. Populates the array with the songs.

If you `console.log` after your append call you'll see you have all the songs in your array.

Comment: I've done this, and even used a DOM button far after the array should be filled, and it still shows up as empty. I'm not sure why its not filling the array.